# String variable passed from php to ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get back a string variable from php to ajax and depending on its value display messages to the user via ajax. Here are the PHP and Javascript ajax codes. I see the string but the comparison in ajax never works.

**PHP**

```
if ($regFull == 'Yes')  //if reg is full
{
    $reg_full="Full";
    echo "$reg_full";
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$.post( 
    $("#enterDetailsForm").attr("action"),
    $("#enterDetailsForm :input").serializeArray(),         
    function(info) {                    
       var result=info;             

       if (result=="Full"){
            alert (result);
       } else {
          $("#displayMessages").empty();
          $("#displayMessages").html(info);
       }    
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried ` echo $reg_full ` instead of  ` echo "$reg_full" `

Comment: @Varun Why would that make a difference?

Comment: check for white spaces that may exists outside of your `<?php ?>` tag, try to remove end tag `?>`

Comment: Oh yes, it won't , i am used to printing out variable without quotes

Comment: Did not make any difference.

Comment: Can you post all the code in the PHP file? Not just a snippet. Exactly how it is in the file, too.

Comment: var resultlength = (result  + '').length; shows 5

Comment: @user3621562 The fifth character is probably a newline, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably some extra whitespace being output by the PHP script. Either you have a blank line before the `<?php` line at the beginning, or the script ends with `?>` followed by a newline -- the newline will be included in the value of `result`. Try:

```
var result = info.trim();
```

to remove any extraneous whitespace.

This is why it's good practice not to end a PHP script with `?>`. It's never needed, and it can introduce extra, unwanted output.

Comment: In my honest opinion, good practice is to use a good code editor that signals this issue.